# How to change the angle origin of a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am using a Math library to get the `Atan2` value between two points.  The issue is that this library (Javascript) returns `Atan2` as a value between $\pi$  and $-\pi$  .

Additionally, it calculates the angle getting larger when going counterclockwise (until $\pi$ is reached). See picture:

[image]

How can I change the "Angle origin" (or whatever the correct name for the 0 / 360 position is) so that instead of being at "3:00" (positive X), it is at "6:00", (negative Y)?

Additionally, what is the best way to change the $\pi$ /$-\pi$ to go from $0$ to $2\pi$?

So far, what I am doing is:

- Calculate my angle using Atan2
- Checking to see if the angle is less than zero, adding $2\pi$ if it is
- Make the angle equal to $3\pi/2$
- Checking to see if the angle is less than zero, adding $2\pi$ if it is

This works but seems like a roundabout way to do this. Specifically the two checks if the angle is negative.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the new angle measured clockwise from the negative $y$-axis then take $\frac32\pi - \theta$ which will be in the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}2 , \frac{5\pi}2\right)$, and if this is $2\pi$ or more then subtract $2\pi$.

Some computer languages might allow something like `mod( pi*3/2 - theta, 2*pi )` to do this without a conditional statement